command on virtual env. pip install clarifai.work on windows Import "clarifai.rest"could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports (module) clarifai
i am working in clarifai. i installed clarifai on my windows as pip install clarifai.
when i wrote from clarifai.rest import ClarifaiApp it is showing error. chatgpt even failed to solve the issues. i checked all the dependencies in my working environment. i could not understand what is the problem.
the error is:
Import "clarifai.rest" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
(module) clarifai

How to resolve it?
notice here how chatgpt solves the question by giving a solution.
image from chatgpt

i checked all the dependencies in my working environment How did you check these exactly?

It looks like the 'Import "clarifai.rest"' part is showing you're trying to use an outdated Clarifai client that's no longer supported. I think ChatGPT might be giving you some old code.
I recommend switching to the new Python SDK, which you can find here: https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-python. We also have other clients and a REST API you can check out: https://docs.clarifai.com/api-guide/api-overview/api-clients/.
